# Wordpress tinymce text formatting

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

In my wp-admin the text editor (tinymce) looks bad. There is no spacing and also the font is bigger and somewhat weird. It's not a problem but just annoying. I do not remember when it happened; so I cannot actually fix this. I added some custom buttons; but that should not be a problem. I also tried turning them off. But no luck. It actually looks like this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you running a custom theme?

Comment: Yes, custom theme. A modified version of foundationpress.

Comment: In that case it you could add a custom CSS stylesheet for the editor so you can correct these issues, see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/